# BIRT - Passing Report URL parameters to DataSource URL

Tags: birt, xmldatasource

I have two servers - one for application(Apache http) and another for BIRT reporting (tomcat). I will have BIRT reports designed with XML Schema files, wherein Datasource URL will be given as

```
http://localhost/myApp/index.php
```

Now, the actual URL to access report is as below

```
http://localhost:8080/birtviewer/frameset?__report=DummyOrder.rptdesign
```

Now, when is pass a parameter in the Report URL, it should be passed to the Datasource URL, as below:

```
Report URL: http://localhost:8080/birtviewer/frameset?__report=DummyOrder.rptdesign&OrderNo=101
DataSourceURL: http://localhost/myApp/index.php?OrderNo=101
```

Is there a way to achieve this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double click on your XML-Data-Source and select "property binding" on the left. Enter a function in to the "XML data source file:" field like below:

```
if (params["OrderNo"] != null){
 "jdbc:mysql://localhost/myApp/index.php?OrderNo=" + params["OrderNo"];
}else{
 "jdbc:mysql://localhost/myApp/index.php";
}
```

There is also a section in the [birt wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Change_Database_URL_at_runtime_based_on_Parameter_(BIRT)) on how to change the data source at runtime.